# Python `mock.patch`: avoid raising exception as part of `side_effect`

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to mock a function that **returns** an `Exception` as opposed to raising it.

I would like to leverage the `side_effects` behavior to return different values when the mocked function is called multiple times.

For example:

`mock.patch.object(some_module, 'SomeFunction', side_effect=[None, SomeException])`

Is there a way for the mock to not raise `SomeException` in the side effects and instead just return the value from the mocked function?

Relevant snippet from `mock` documentation: `Alternatively side_effect can be an exception class or instance. In this case the exception will be raised when the mock is called.`

Comment: Most of the time, I'd reconsider why a function is returning an exception in the first place.